# Rally Rest API - 'Batch' processing of Project Permissions

Tags: c#, api, rally

I'm currently using the `C# Rally Rest API` and setting project permissions for a user. This is working but permissions are being set one at a time. So, if a user needs access to 5 projects, I'm making 5 `Create ProjectPermission` calls. What I would really like to do is make one call into Rally with all the necessary information so it can update all the permissions at once.

I would also like to be able to set `team membership` in the same call. In looking at the revision history for a user, I know that Rally, internally, can update all that information in one call--since it shows only 1 revision for a bunch of changes. To accomplish the same work using my current method causes a revision for each change to happen.

Is there a way to 'batch' process these types of request to make them more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are following the best/only available approach via Webservices with your N_Projects x Create ProjectPermission calls. While the User Revision History may record a single change for multiple Permission Grants made via the Rally User Interface, Rally's Webservices API requires a WSAPI call per permission.